# Problema con ventana modal de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, modal

Cuando abro una ventana modal con bootstrap me aparece un cuadro blanco detrás de ésta ventana, como puedo quitar ésto?

Estoy usando la libreria Bootstrap 3.3.6

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

```
<div class="modal fade" id="miModal0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
           <h6 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">DiagramaRelaciones</h6>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
           <iframe name="fram" src="Ciencias Sociales\DiagramaRelaciones.png" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Este es el boton que lo activa

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#miModal0">DiagramaRelaciones</button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Yaheel, te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido de la pagina y revises como hacer una buena pregunta. Ya que es muy dificil que alguien pueda ayudarte por ejemplo sin ver el codigo de lo que estas ejecutando o sin saber las versiones de las librerias que usas. Por favor editala y agrega mas informacion.

Comment: Tu código como lo muestras funciona bien, no aparece ningúna ventana blanca tras el modal